# Since when does OPENFILENAME.lpstrDefExt support extensions with more than three characters?

Tags: winapi

The current version of the Windows API documentation of the [`OPENFILENAME` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) states (emphasis mine):

> **lpstrDefExt**
>   Type: `LPCTSTR`
>
> The default extension. `GetOpenFileName` and `GetSaveFileName` append this extension to the file name if the user fails to type an extension. **This string can be any length, but only the first three characters are appended.** The string should not contain a period (.). If this member is `NULL` and the user fails to type an extension, no extension is appended.

This is incorrect, as executing the following MVCE on Windows 10 (Build 17134.5) shows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t filename[256] = { 0 };

    OPENFILENAMEW ofn =
    {
        .lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAMEW),
        .lpstrFilter = L"All Files\0*.*\0\0",
        .lpstrFile = filename,
        .nMaxFile = sizeof(filename),
        .lpstrDefExt = L"xlsx"
    };

    BOOL ret = GetSaveFileNameW(&ofn);

    if (ret != 0)
    { 
        wprintf(L"%s\r\n", filename);
    }
}
```

Entering `test` in the Save File dialog box yields `C:\Users\...\Documents\test.xlsx`, not `C:\Users\...\Documents\test.xls`, as the documentation claims.

When did this change, i.e., on which target systems can I rely on `lpstrDefExt` supporting more than three characters?

Comment: [_"note this is stale documentation, possibly dating back to Windows 3.1 when names were limited to 8.3 format. At least since Vista, it accepted longer (just confirmed myself on Windows 10 too)"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310173/is-there-anyway-to-make-something-automatically-add-selected-file-extension-to-f#comment53538603_20310327).

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thanks that's very relevant! *"at least since Vista..."* would be perfect, since I need to support Windows 7/Server 2008 and above.

Comment: On Vista and later, `Get(Open|Save)FileName()` are wrappers for the newer `IFile(Open|Save)Dialog` interfaces (unless you specify the `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` flag), which don't have many of the same limitations as the old APIs.

Comment: Also, since Vista the recommendation is to use the [Common Item Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913.aspx), rather than GetOpenFilename.

Comment: This goes back 25 years, starting with the emulation of MS-Dos 8.3 filenames.  A file named longfilename.xlsx has an extra directory entry that will resemble longfi~1.xls.  Which matches a *.xls wildcard.  This support is overdue to be turned off, especially so for x64 versions that can't support 16-bit code anymore, but today still enabled by default.  All you can do about it is verify the names you get back.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Just for fun, I just tried to add a hook. It still supports the long file name extension, but, wow, the resulting dialog brought back 16-bit memories: https://imgur.com/a/bEPtMTL

Comment: @theB: That's good advice. In my case, that's not an option, since we call the dialog from VBA, and these dialogs [don't work well with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907866/87698). I just created the C program as a MVCE.

Comment: @Heinzi You can get the Win95-XP dialog with a hook, you just have to include the Explorer flag, otherwise you get the Windows 3 style.